# How do I get the currently matched line from a compilation-error-regexp-alist file function?

Tags: emacs, elisp, compile-mode

I'm running a command with `compile` so I can link from error messages to the associated source, but I need to transform a chunk of the content of matched lines to get the file to link to. (The line shows a clojure namespace, like `foo-bar.quux`, which needs to be transformed into `foo_bar/quux.clj`.)

The documentation of `compilation-error-regexp-alist` says, in part,

> Each elt has the form (REGEXP FILE [LINE COLUMN TYPE HYPERLINK HIGHLIGHT...]). ... FILE can also have the form (FILE FORMAT...), where the FORMATs (e.g. \"%s.c\") will be applied in turn to the recognized file
>   name, until a file of that name is found.  Or FILE can also be a function that returns (FILENAME) or (RELATIVE-FILENAME . DIRNAME). In the former case, FILENAME may be relative or absolute.

When I add entries to `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` and `compilation-error-regexp-alist` with a function in `FILE` position, my function is called with no arguments. How do I get the matched line inside that function?

Comment: Calling the function is the correct behaviour (though I agree that's not very clever). As for getting the matched error, have you tried using `(match-string 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening `compile.el` and then searching with `C-s (funcall` jumped me to:

```
           (setq file (if (functionp file) (funcall file)
                        (match-string-no-properties file))))
```

which seems to be the relevant spot and shows that the functions is indeed called with no arguments and that the `match-data` is still very much valid, so you can extract the file name with `(match-string <the-file-sub-group>)`.

Comment: Works great. Thanks. I'm new to emacs lisp and surprised (and a little disturbed) at how much is done via mutable global state.